# Why is this not getting triggered?

Tags: javascript, function, sockets, socket.io

I'm calling scoreBoard() elsewhere, and it runs the console.log inside the function, but it does not go further to the next function? Can anyone please give me some insight why this is? As I only want to call this socket.on or at least draw the table if the player has logged in.

```
var scoreBoard = function(){

 console.log('Gets into here, does not go into the next function');

        socket.on('allScores', function(data){
            console.log('inside');
            var playerScores = data;
            // console.log(playerScores);

            document.write('<table>');
            document.write('<tr> <th>Player</th> <th>Score</th> </tr>');

            for(var i = 0; i < playerScores.length; i++)
            {
            document.write('<tr><td>' + playerScores[i].username + '</td><td>' + playerScores[i].score + '</td></tr>');
            }
            document.write('</table>');
        })
}
```

This is not running

```
console.log('inside');
```

Comment: because you don't receive `allScores` events

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: If I put the allScores outside that function it works perfectly, soon as I put it into a function it will not trigger.

Comment: You should never use document.write after a page load and document.write is NOT like building a string. When you write out the opening tag, the browser closes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `console.log('inside');` is inside an event listener. It's not inside a function that would get executed sequentially after the previous `console.log` call.

If you are sure the event is being generated, then it's only being generated before the `scoreBoard()` function is called. Since you're only attaching the event listener inside that function it only starts listening for the `allScores` event after you run `scoreBoard()`.

The solution is to move the `socket.on('allScores', function(data){ ... })` part to outside the `scoreBoard()` function body.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the only way, but then it draws the scores when I don't want it too that's why, but thanks for the info!

Comment: That's another question then ;)